# Unable to get current cost of subscription using Azure Runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-runbook

I am trying to get the subscription current cost using azure runbook but a 'Bad Request' error is displayed. The same script is working fine on my local machine.

FYI: I updated the Az.Accounts and Az.Billing modules in the Runbook gallery.

Powershell:

```
Write-Host "Get the subscription current billing period"
$currentBillingPeriod = Get-AzBillingPeriod -MaxCount 1
$startDate = $currentBillingPeriod.BillingPeriodStartDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
Write-Host "currentBillingPeriod startDate : " $startDate
$endDate = $currentBillingPeriod.BillingPeriodEndDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
Write-Host "currentBillingPeriod endDate : " $endDate

Write-Host "Get the subscription current cost"
$currentCost = Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate | Measure-Object -Property PretaxCost -Sum
Write-Host "Current Cost of Subscription : " $currentCost.Sum
```

Output on local powershell:

```
Get the subscription current billing period
currentBillingPeriod startDate :  11-08-2021
currentBillingPeriod endDate :  10-09-2021
Get the subscription current cost
Current Cost of Subscription :  497.729683916108
```

Output when run on Azure Runbook:

```
Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest' At line:44 char:16 + ... rrentCost = Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate $startDate -EndDa ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail], ErrorResponseException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Consumption.Cmdlets.UsageDetails.GetAzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail
```

Debug Output:

```
Body:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "400",
    "message": "Invalid time range, start: 2021-11-08 end: 2021-10-09 (Request ID: dc5f1cc4-4361-4378-adfd-0b9065ecbce3)"
  }
}  

Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail : A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest' At line:44 char:16 + ... rrentCost = Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate $startDate -EndDa ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotImplemented: (:) [Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail], HostException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HostFunctionNotImplemented,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Consumption.Cmdlets.UsageDetails.GetAzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to resolve this issue. Actually, i am passing date format in ("dd-MM-yyyy") for 'BillingPeriodStartDate' and 'BillingPeriodEndDate'.
The date format should be ("yyyy-MM-dd")

```
$startDate = $currentBillingPeriod.BillingPeriodStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$endDate = $currentBillingPeriod.BillingPeriodEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

I don't know why it is correctly working with ("dd-MM-yyyy") format in my local machine. After using ("yyyy-MM-dd") format, It is working on both local and Azure runbook.

Debug logs really help me to find out the exact problem.